# Invalid Handle when using SetConsoleWindowInfo

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I'm new to C++ and decided to challenge myself with a small console game. To avoid typical flickering.
Fromm what I got from MSDN docs I should be using a Console Buffer, but I took it easy and started from simple things like changing Window title and resizing it.
The small program I wrote was meant to do just that, but for some reason I get Error Code 6 (should be "invalid handle") when I execute the SetConsoleWindowInfo.

Anyone who can point me in the right direction with this? Thank you in advance

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

HANDLE  wHandle, bHandle;

SMALL_RECT wSize = { 0,0,100,100 };

int main() {
    wHandle = GetConsoleWindow();
    if (wHandle == NULL) {
        printf("Handle is Null");
    }
    SetConsoleTitle(L"NewTitle");
    if (!SetConsoleWindowInfo(wHandle, TRUE, &wSize)) {
        printf("SetConsoleWindowInfo (%d)\n", GetLastError());

    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `GetConsoleWindow` return window handle (`HWND`) when `SetConsoleWindowInfo` require handle (`HANDLE`)  to the console screen buffer. this is absolute different things. you need use `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)` for `SetConsoleWindowInfo`

Comment: You should generally not use `GetConsoleWindow`, the console window should be treated as off-limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

HANDLE  wHandle, bHandle;

//SMALL_RECT wSize = { 0,0,100,100 }; // If SetConsoleWindow fails with code 87, then this is too big!
SMALL_RECT wSize = { 0,0,60,20 }; // Works on my screen!

int main() {
//  wHandle = GetConsoleWindow(); 
    wHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); // See comment by RbMm
    if (wHandle == NULL) {
        printf("Handle is Null");
    }
//  SetConsoleTitle(L"NewTitle"); // Don't use a wide character string!
    SetConsoleTitle("NewTitle");
    if (!SetConsoleWindowInfo(wHandle, TRUE, &wSize)) {
        printf("SetConsoleWindowInfo (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Feel free to ask, if you don't understand anything I've changed (or why I've changed it), but the comments address some of the issues.

Comment: No, it does not. Looking at the output of a single language implementation will not ever allow you to see language rules.

Comment: yes, concrete generated code nothing prove, but from general language rules - function arguments evaluated **before** function call. and in concrete code - only `GetLastError()` subject to evaluation.